# LibGDX с рекламой Admob

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Видел пару инструкции в интернете по подключение баннеров в приложение, но все они абсолютно разные. В общем прошу подсказать будет ли данный код нормально отображать рекламу?

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {

private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-***********/**********";
protected AdView adView;
protected View gameView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
    cfg.useAccelerometer = false;
    cfg.useCompass = false;

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    layout.setLayoutParams(params);

    AdView admobView = createAdView();
    layout.addView(admobView);
    View gameView = createGameView(cfg);
    layout.addView(gameView);

    setContentView(layout);
    startAdvertising(admobView);
}

private AdView createAdView() {
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    adView.setLayoutParams(params);
    adView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    return adView;
}

private View createGameView(AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg) {
    gameView = initializeForView(new PipeGame(), cfg);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());
    gameView.setLayoutParams(params);
    return gameView;
}

private void startAdvertising(AdView adView) {
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (adView != null) adView.resume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    if (adView != null) adView.pause();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (adView != null) adView.destroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

Comment: Т.е. вы не пробовали и хотите чтоб мы вместо вас попробовали? Так то код на рабочий похож

Comment: я то попробовал, но рекламы нету, она появится только когда приложение в Play Market добавлю ?

Comment: и как управлять рекламой из приложения? я например хочу межстраничную пихнуть и ставить ее когда проигрываешь

Comment: Что значит "нету"? Банеер на экране не видно или в нём тестовая реклама? Или он пуст? Что в логах у вас? Вы зарегались в AdMob? Все ли пункты из их доки сделали? Ключи приложения/баннера точно свои подстваили в пример? Очень мало инфы - вам не помочь. А полноэкранки в вашем коде нет и её надо отдельно настраивать. В доке вся инфа есть

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/2A8Lg
нету просто никакой рекламы, ни тестового, ни обычного.  Ключ точной свой.

Comment: Ошибка может быть в тысяче мест. Гадать можно долго. Очень долго

Answer (score 0):

Выкладывайте на плеймаркет в режиме тестирования. Даёте доступ тестерам (друзьям / знакомым). У них должно всё отображаться.
Подробнее в КОНСОЛИ РАЗРАБОТЧИКА google - справа - Возможности для публикации приложений - Разделы:
Альфа- и бета-тестирование
Поэтапный выпуск приложения